# NFC tag for google cardboard app

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-cardboard

Being extremely new to android vr development, this caught my attention.From the developers sample, its seen that the app uses nfc permission. This explanation on the developers site doesnt tell much about the usage. Why's it required?

> android.permission.NFC permission is required by the Google VR SDK to
>   access the NFC tag of the VR viewer.

Just understanding why.

Comment: What do you need help with? Adding the tag? Or just understanding why?

Answer (score 0):

You can program an NFC tag to open the app when it close to a tag (for example when you put your phone in the cardboard), I am guessing that is why it is in the example app.